# MySQL Syntax error on a delete from a select set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dataset, syntax-error

I had a select statement which selected the oldest set of data in a table with an Inner Join

```
SELECT DateAndTime
    ,Val
    ,NumIndex
    ,TagName
    ,floattable.TagIndex
FROM taglogging.floattable
INNER JOIN tagtable ON tagtable.TagIndex = floattable.TagIndex
WHERE DateAndTime = oldest;
```

This works well and does the job in returning the data set.

I want to now delete from the data set, any record where the value column is outside its min, max range which is defined in another database.

I did this

```
DELETE
FROM taglogging.floattable
WHERE Val IN (
        SELECT DateAndTime
            ,Val
            ,NumIndex
            ,TagName
            ,floattable.TagIndex
        FROM taglogging.floattable
        INNER JOIN tagtable ON tagtable.TagIndex = floattable.TagIndex
        WHERE DateAndTime = oldest
        ) < taglogging_archive.tagmembers.tagMember_minValue
    OR Val > taglogging_archive.tagMember_minValue;
```

and in doing so, got a syntax error:

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Does anyone see the error in my syntax :( I am new to MySQL syntax but after moving from MSSQL i was confident in the logic of my query.

Kind Regards,

Jordan

Comment: Aaaahh this makes sense. I was thinking it would be able to sense the Val column I was referencing based on my SELECT query!

Thank you all for the clarification of this :) I will bear this in mind for the future :)

Comment: hahaha changed :P i had a slight "paws" in my thought, @Strawberry :P

Comment: :-) These days I find I can barely (see what I did there) string 5 words together without making some kind of mistake.

Comment: Incidentally, note that a subquery is not required here. A join would work just as well (and perhaps better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query, the select statement should have only one column name in respect of `Val` column.

Your query should be like this:

```
DELETE from taglogging.floattable WHERE Val IN 
  (SELECT Val
      FROM taglogging.floattable 
        INNER JOIN tagtable ON tagtable.TagIndex = floattable.TagIndex
          WHERE DateAndTime = oldest) < taglogging_archive.tagmembers.tagMember_minValue 
             OR Val > taglogging_archive.tagMember_minValue;
```

As the error says.

Answer (score 1):

`Operand should contain 1 column(s)` tells everything. Btw, this is not a syntax error, it is a semantic error, so your syntax has to be correct.

MySQL is complaining `SELECT DateAndTime, Val, NumIndex, TagName, floattable.TagIndex` is fetching more than one column. The `IN` operator requires exactly ONE column to be returned in the `SELECT` statement, you are returning 5.

As you use `DELETE from taglogging.floattable WHERE Val IN`, I would guess that you would want to use `SELECT Val FROM`...

Answer (score 1):

you can't use Val IN `(SELECT DateAndTime, Val, NumIndex,....` you have to use Val IN 
`(SELECT DateAndTime FROM ....`. If you use in with only one value on the left the subquery should return only 1 column (which doesn't mean 1 row).

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the error is telling you:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Do you have anything in the query which has more than one column?  Yup:

```
... WHERE Val IN 
(SELECT DateAndTime, Val, NumIndex, TagName, floattable.TagIndex ...
```

How exactly do you expect the query engine to make sense of that?  Which column should it be looking for `Val` in?

Only use the column you need:

```
... WHERE Val IN
(SELECT Val ...
```

Answer (score 0):

error its self solution.. Your select query is return more than one column just try below

```
DELETE from taglogging.floattable WHERE Val IN 
(SELECT Val  
FROM taglogging.floattable 
INNER JOIN tagtable 
ON tagtable.TagIndex = floattable.TagIndex
WHERE DateAndTime = oldest) < taglogging_archive.tagmembers.tagMember_minValue 
OR Val > taglogging_archive.tagMember_minValue;
```